# Python:Reading specific line from user and show the line

Tags: python-3.x, computer-science

problem: Write your own version of code that prompts for the name of the file to read, and the number of lines to print.

**Can anyone help me to solve this problem in python?**
[image: Output should be like the image bellow]

I tried to like this :

```
import linecache

line=int(input("Line: "))

print(linecache.getline("Test.txt",line))
```

but can't solve the last problem where it said if the input is greater then the lines that  already exist, all lines will be shown

Answer (score 0):

```
file=input('File name: ')
print(os.access(file,os.F_OK))#check whether file is available or not
no_of_lines=int(input('Lines: '))
file_length=0

with open(file,'r') as f:
    file_length=len(f.readlines())

with open(file,'r') as f:
    if file_length<no_of_lines:
            print(f.read())
    else:
        for i in range(no_of_lines):
            print(f.readline().rstrip('\n'))
```

Comment: reason why I used open() twice because once operation has finished on the file, connection automatically closes

Comment: @Shihab Omar I think your doubt has rectified